# Performance Issue while generating random numbers and inserting into an Array with already n numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, random, heap-memory

Here is the code that I am using for generating random numbers and inserting them into an array. Say if I want to generate 1000000 random numbers and insert into an array with already MAXSIZE number of elements at a random position generated. the below logic is actually crashing my system due to low heap memory for a very long number.

Here MAXSIZE = 1000000

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
{
    int randomNo = rand() % MAXSIZE;
    randArray[i] = randomNo;
}

//Inserting Random numbers for an Array at a random position
    for (int i = position, j = 0; i < (2 * size); i++, j++)
    {
        bArray[j] = aArray[i];
        aArray[i] = randArray[j];
    }

    for (int i = position + size, j = 0; i < ((2 * size)); i++, j++)
    {
        aArray[i] = bArray[j];
    }
```

Can someone suggests a better way of writing the code here so that the system doesn't crash for a very large set of numbers and put it in an array.

For example, Initially I will be having 10 numbers in an array. Now I will be generating 10 more random numbers and insert it into an position that is randomly generated with in 0-10. So the output becomes 20 elements now. For this in the first place I am generating array with size 2*10. In my question the number is 100000 or more instead of 10.

To be more precise:

What I want is: 
eg: Intial array Arr[10] is 1, 3, 5, 2, 6 
Random array generated is: 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 
Random Position generated is: 3 
Final Array should be: 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2, 6
NOTE: Numbers can be repetitive

Comment: Are all those numbers needed simultaneously? Can not they be generated one at a time when needed?

Comment: Just a note: these random numbers are not necessarily uniformly distributed. For instance, in the range of `rand`, there might be more numbers that `% MAXSIZE == 0` than `% MAXSIZE == MAXSIZE - 1`.

Comment: *What* heap memory? I don't see anything that's specifically on the heap (or on the stack either for that matter). Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Then tell us *where* in *your* code the crashes happens.

Comment: What are `size` and `position` variables? If `2*size - position` > `MAXSIZE` you will go beyond `randArray` limits in the second `for` loop.

Comment: Here it goes. Intially I will be having 10 numbers in an array. Now I will be generating 10 more random numbers and insert it into an position that is randomly generated with in 0-10. So the output becomes 20 elements now.
For this in the first place I am generating array with size 2*10.
In my question the number is 100000 or more instead of 10.

@Alex: size is nothing but 100000, position is a rand position that is generated between 0 - 100000

Answer (score 0):

I made assumptions:

- Random numbers will be only used to populate final array and nowhere else
- Array have already desired size.

Actual code:

```
srand(time(NULL));
// position -> position at which numbers should be inserted
// size -> size of table
// n -> how many random number should be inserted
if(position + n > size) n = size - position;
for (int i = size; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(i >= position + n) {
        aArray[i] = aArray[i-n];
    }
    if(i >= position && i <= position + n) {
        aArray[i] = rand() % MAXSIZE;
    }
}
```

It would save quite a lot computation/memory if original array was created with size that will fill any following iterations. This algorithm will still works if size is too small. Just copy initial array into something bigger.

Comment: What I want is:
eg: Intial array Arr[10] is 1, 3, 5, 2, 6
Random array generated is: 2, 3, 5, 6, 7
Random Position generated is: 3
Final Array should be: 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2, 6

Comment: Edited it accordingly. You should be seeing the example now in the end of the question